# Regex DO NOT match text inside <a> tag

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a link tag `<a href="{url}" title="{keyword}">keyword</a>` onto a given text when it find that keyword. But that keyword should NOT already inside an `<a></a>` tag already and it should also not match href and title attribute.  I'm using PHP

For example:

*NOTE. My usecase text don't have space

**Text** = `<p>thisiscatfish</p>`

**Keyword** = catfish

**Expected Output** = `<p>thisis<a href="#" title="catfish">catfish</a></p>`

## BUT if

**Text** = `<p>iam<a href="www.catfish.com" title="catfish">catfish</a></p>`

**Keyword** = fish

**Expected Output**: `<p>iam<a href="www.catfish.com" title="catfish">catfish</a></p>`

*NOTE it should NOT match href and title attribute and replace it.

### What I have tried  https://paiza.io/projects/WYvDVTUMDg0kFOUo6NEHpQ

### Problem

My solution so far it matching and replacing href and title as well. How can I modify my regex to not match href and title attribute as well?

```
function replaceText($text, $keyword, $url) {
    
    $pattern = "/(?!>)$keyword(?!<\/a>)/i";
    
    $replaceWith = "<a href='$url' title='$keyword'>$keyword</a>";
    
    $newText = preg_replace($pattern, $replaceWith, $text);
    
    return $newText;
}

$text = '<p>thisiscatfish</p>';

$newText = replaceText($text, 'catfish', 'www.catfish.com');

$newText2 = replaceText($newText, 'fish', 'www.fish.com');
echo $newText2;
```

Comment: You can do this by use of [`(*SKIP)(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) and further I'd recommend to use `preg_quote` for escaping the input. Change to `$pattern = "/<a\s[^><]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|".preg_quote($keyword,"/")."/i";`. Probably wiser to use some html parser for such kind of tasks, not sure : )

Comment: @bobblebubble Thanks alot, your pattern does exclude matching the title and href attribute but still match the text inside <a></a> So it have nested link now. So I added original regex to become `$pattern = "/<a\s[^><]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|(?!>)".preg_quote($keyword,"/")."(?!<\/a>)/i"`  And it seems working great. Any suggestion?  Otherwise please post as answer and I'll accept

Answer (score -1):

What you are attempting to do, should not be attempted. RegEx cannot parse HTML. *Regular* Expressions are for regular languages, HTML is an *Irregular* language. Therefore it simply cannot handle what you are asking for.

To further emphasize this point, let me point you in the direction of one of the most [powerful answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/8700809) to garnish this forum.